# Spotify Android SDK and kaaes Web API AccessToken missmatch?

Tags: java, android, asp.net-web-api, spotify

Im doing a android app and using spotifys SDK. Since they don't support metadata I added kaaes/spotify-web-api-android.

I have some problem using the SDK provided Access token in the web api. According to the developer at spotify this should work.

When grabbing a token string from: 
https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/console/get-playlist/
everything works fine but when using response.getAccessToken(); I get a 400 bad request.
Also when comparing the 2 string the one from the SDK is much longer.

Any idea why this is?

Anyway here is the code:
Here is where I get the Token from the SDK:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    // Check if result comes from the correct activity
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {

        AuthenticationResponse response = AuthenticationClient.getResponse(resultCode, intent);
        response.getAccessToken();
        if (response.getType() == AuthenticationResponse.Type.TOKEN) {
            ACCESS_TOKEN = response.getAccessToken();
            Config playerConfig = new Config(this, response.getAccessToken(), CLIENT_ID);
            spotifyPlayer = Spotify.getPlayer(playerConfig, this, new Player.InitializationObserver() {
                @Override
                public void onInitialized(Player player) {
                    spotifyPlayer.addConnectionStateCallback(MainActivity.this);
                    spotifyPlayer.addPlayerNotificationCallback(MainActivity.this);
                    //spotifyPlayer.play("spotify:user:decerto:playlist:0BZvnsfuqmnLyj6WVRuSte");
                    //spotifyPlayer.play("spotify:user:decerto:starred");
                   // spotifyPlayer.play("spotify:user:decerto:playlist:0GzWuVLoPgyIHBGkt2mE1u");


                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable throwable) {
                    Log.e("MainActivity", "Could not initialize player: " + throwable.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And here is where I add the token to the api:

```
 api.setAccessToken(MainActivity.ACCESS_TOKEN);

    SpotifyService spotify = api.getService();
```

this will generate a 400 bad request but if I instead just grab a token from spotify API console it works fine:

```
api.setAccessToken("BQD8DnYp64EATmK7KCMVwc_DSN0FCdPgN0VeSsRzGpxYgjji_M8Lyai-bbTe7WygFN4q5bT-cVODfYvUuxv6OW71P9YNa5XG9ZesX2B28t8SgKXm9_PifYnjpH4FmLaOJjnYz4ZdzNdidDhn5hY4nPoPrn0");
```

Comment: Could you please provide the error description for that 400 Bad Request response?

Comment: the error I get from the spotifycallback is: 400 Only valid bearer authentication supported

Comment: This was solved. I feel a bit stupid since it was a classic user mistake(and a really dumb one). I tried to get authentication for the API before the response.getAccessToken(); happened.